# What is the difference between "Project References" and "Paths and Symbols -> References" in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, project, eclipse-cdt

When opening project's Properties dialog, I see a list of reference projects under `C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> References`. Immediately below that, there is an entry named `Project References` containing a similar list.

What is the difference between the lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference the C++ Development Environment Guide states is this:

> Unlike the Eclipse Common References page, this page allows setting
>   references to specific configurations.

So you can e.g. tell Eclipse to create the Release build of a referenced project before building the project which references it.

Read more here: [C/C++ Project Properties, Paths and Symbols, Project References](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_general_pns_ref.htm)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the Common References page is a subset of the C/C++ References page. It is probably left there for backward compatibility or something alike. Like many other elements of eclipse, it just adds unnecessary clutter.

Comment: FYI there is a bug in Eclipse where when you set `C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> References` sometimes it will also check the box in `Project References` too in a random way. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495142